# Make Dokku stay on major version

Tags: dokku

On my `package.json` file I have the following below. As expected it is installing version 16.x but I would like it to only install the latest 12.x. Is there a way to setup the app to only do that?

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=12.19.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to just use `12.x` in your `package.json`. ([Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)/[NPM Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines))

```json
"engines": {
  "node": "12.x"
}
```

You can use [NPM's semver syntax](https://semver.npmjs.com/) to define supported versions. If you only want versions greater than 12.19.0 but still within 12.x, you can use `^12.19.0`.